# Выполнение команды git pull в jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

При выполнении простого пайплайна в jenkins по типу:

```
...
stages {
      stage('git pull') {
          steps {
              git branch: "mybranch",
                  credentialsId: 'mycredential',
                  url: 'git@git.ru:repo/123.git'
                  sh 'git pull'
...
```

Пайплайн уходит на ошибку, а в console output я вижу:

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ git pull
git@git.ru: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Почему он пытается пулить не git@git.ru:repo/123.git, а git@git.ru? 
Помогите решить проблему

Comment: команды `sh 'git pull'` не нужно. команда `git ...` уже скачала исходники. дальше работйте с ними.

Comment: Да и правда, как я сразу не заметил, спасибо!